# Postgresql vs MySQL Subpartitioning support

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have use case where my every query has this filters `date` and `country`, so i want to have table where i can partitioned it by date under each date partition, i can subpartitioned/clusterd by country. So All queries will be very fast `insert`, `update` and `delete`.

For MYSQL i can see this i can use `PARTITION` and `SUBPARTITION`  clause but does Postgresql support this i can't find any straight forward solution ?

Which will be the best fit in this scenario, as my data contains 500 Millions of rows, and i need to created indexes on additional `2-4` columns ?

Comment: why? partitioning doesn't increase the speed

Comment: @nbk Since my every query will have partition filter so it will not increase the speed ?

Comment: Yes, in PostgreSQL you can partition the partitions. And these can be partitioned as well. 500 million records is imho not a lot, that’s what we have in a single partition, one month of data

Comment: Partitioning divides the data based on a linear algorithm (`n`). Indexes divide the data by an exponentially more efficient algorithm (typically `log(n)`). So correctly implemented indexes are always going to be more performant than using partitioning. Just like nbk said, partitioning isn't meant for performance improvements - for most cases. It's a data management tool instead. One use case it *could* be helpful in, is if you had rolling data, and you wanted to delete an entire partition at a time, then you can drop the entire partition as one, instead of deleting every row in it.

Comment: I have never found any benefit to subpartitions, especially not for performance.  What do you hope to gain?  Yes, 500M rows is big.  A better composite index is almost always at least slightly faster than partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres you can create subpartitions within partitions e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    my_date DATE NOT NULL,
    country TEXT NOT NULL,
    ...
) PARTITION BY RANGE (my_date);

CREATE TABLE my_table_2019 PARTITION OF my_table
    FOR VALUES FROM ('2019-01-01') TO ('2020-01-01')
    PARTITION BY LIST (country);

CREATE TABLE my_table_2019_USA PARTITION OF my_table_2019
    FOR VALUES IN ('USA');

CREATE TABLE my_table_2019_Canada PARTITION OF my_table_2019
    FOR VALUES IN ('Canada');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have this composite index, with the columns in this order.

```
INDEX(country, date)
```

And don't bother with partitioning or subpartitioning.

For further discussion, let's see some queries that you hope to speed up.